# Searching for strings with BeautifulSoup and write to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I Need reslove 3 problem：

1. I'm trying to write a simple program in python that parses a web page for the table of table id="dgContract".
2. store this table of page 1 ,page2,page3....pageN to mongodb, i don't know how to opration mongodb.
3. parses Selected "Detail" links of content store to mongodb.if open Selected "view" ,need add http://www.xxx.com/ like http://www.xxx.com/LicConDisp.aspx?CID=xxxxx

   open picture in new windows will clear！！！

[image: THIS is source table snap]

my code：

```
import urllib2,cookielib,sys                                                           
import urllib,string                                                                   
import cStringIO,Image,re                                                                               
import BeautifulSoup          # For processing HTML                                    
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup     # For processing XML                  
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import configparser                                                                    
from pymongo import Connection                                                         
import codecs                                                                          
import sitecustomize                                                                   
import chardet

host = 'localhost'      
database = 'test'       
collection = 'compinfo' 

f=file('copy of out4.html','r')              
html=f.read()                                
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))          
table = soup.find('table', id="dgContract")  
rows = table.findAll('tr')                   
store = []                                   
for tr in rows:                              
  cols = tr.findAll('td')                    
  row = []                                   
  for td in cols:                            
    try:                                     
      row.append(''.join(td.find(text=True)))
    except Exception:                        
      row.append('')                         
  store.append('|'.join(row))                

print '\n'.join(store)
```

But output like this： open picture in new windows will clear！！！

[image: run Python code result .............!!!]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

```
<HEAD>

    <title>查询</title>

    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">

    <meta content="C#" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">

    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">

    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />


    <link href="css/user.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">

    .STYLE1 {FONT-SIZE: 12px; COLOR: #ffffff}

    .STYLE2 {FONT-SIZE: 14px; COLOR: #000000}

    .STYLE45 {FONT-SIZE: 12px}

    .STYLE51 {FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: "宋体"}

    .STYLE52 {FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-FAMILY: "宋体"}

    </style>

</HEAD>

<body background="images/bg.jpg" MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">

    <form name="Form1" method="post" action="ContractSearcher.aspx" id="Form1">

        <div align="center">

            <table borderColor="#c7c7c7" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="1">

                <tr>

                    <td class="tdBorder">

                        <!-- content -->

                        <!--显示用户信息条 -->
                        <!--内容主体：左侧为菜单，右侧为内容显示区 -->

                        <table height="350" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="760" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <!--左侧菜单项 -->
                                <td width="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                <!--右侧内容显示区 -->
                                <td vAlign="top" width="815" bgColor="#ffffff">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="tdbigmidcenter">
                                            <table class="tablebigContent" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="dgContract" width="815">
                                                <tr bgcolor="PapayaWhip">
                                                <td>numb</td><td>用户1</td><td>用户2</td>
                                                <td>作者</td>
                                                <td align="center">接受时间</td><td align="center">发送</td>
                                                <td align="center">详情</td>
                                                <td align="center">状态</td>
                                                <td>version</td>
                                               </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140331-120</td><td width="14%">

                                                                A公司

                                                            </td><td width="14%">A学校</td><td width="5%">david</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-31 15:19:45">2014-3-31</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                未发送



                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=91e13d7a-e812-428d-a5c2-532778ea4e89" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=91e13d7a-e812-428d-a5c2-532778ea4e89">已结束[<font color=red>通过</font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140328-106</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                A公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">M公司</td><td width="5%">王明</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 16:16:53">2014-3-28</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                未发货



                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=72648278-dbe3-4577-9154-23182e349b33" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=72648278-dbe3-4577-9154-23182e349b33">已结束[<font color=red>HOPECE140328-5 </font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                B公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">C中心</td><td width="5%">王明</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-12 15:07:12">2014-3-12</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:28:37">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=0526a587-85dc-484e-88f4-87967546678f" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014479" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=0526a587-85dc-484e-88f4-87967546678f">已结束[<font color=red>HOPETE140313-1 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140306-001</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                A公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">A中心</td>
    <td width="5%">JACK</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-7 9:48:47">2014-3-7</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:28:46">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=dfec1630-e1d4-478c-9feb-415eedbd6184" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014479" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=dfec1630-e1d4-478c-9feb-415eedbd6184">已结束[<font color=red>HOPETE140317-4 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140228-102</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                G公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">F公司</td>
    <td width="5%">david</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                未通过

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                未发货



                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=9e19e1c9-7644-4392-9bdd-89e2bac346cd" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=9e19e1c9-7644-4392-9bdd-89e2bac346cd">已作废</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140228-005</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                T公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">J公司 </td>
    <td width="5%">jack</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-2-28 14:54:26">2014-2-28</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:55:11">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=45039bfb-ccb8-49f4-b8fe-27bc8cf59803" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014480" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=45039bfb-ccb8-49f4-b8fe-27bc8cf59803">已结束[<font color=red>HOPECE140228-10</font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140228-002</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                S公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">V公司</td>
    <td width="5%">张军</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-2-28 14:13:23">2014-2-28</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:28:54">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=02a8d406-a826-4a5a-b466-f4bca2640307" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014479" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=02a8d406-a826-4a5a-b466-f4bca2640307">已结束[<font color=red>HOPETE140307-4 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                A公司

                                                            </td>
    <td width="14%">W公司</td><td width="5%">jack</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-2-28 14:13:38">2014-2-28</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:29:03">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=2684c70a-baea-4da4-911b-19cdbe627fd9" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014479" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=2684c70a-baea-4da4-911b-19cdbe627fd9">已结束[<font color=red>HOPETE140307-3 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140228-013</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                B公司

                                                            </td><td width="14%">V公司</td>
                      <td width="5%">rose</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-2-28 14:19:28">2014-2-28</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-28 10:28:23">2014-3-28</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=1204ad5e-4552-43af-a650-19b93f9d2514" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014479" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=1204ad5e-4552-43af-a650-19b93f9d2514">已结束[<font color=red>HOPETE140307-2 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr>

    <td width="21%">HOPE-HT-YX-S-140226-018</td>
    <td width="14%">

                                                                C公司

                                                            </td><td width="14%">A中心</td>
                      <td width="5%">david</td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-2-26 14:56:14">2014-2-26</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a href="#" title="2014-3-14 15:27:44">2014-3-14</a><br>

                                                                [<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="7%">

                                                                <a href="LicConDisp.aspx?CID=a04cdcd2-5b5c-4182-a22d-a29399ab6991" target="_blank">查看</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="10%">

                                                                <a title="9900014388" href="ConStatusDisp.aspx?CID=a04cdcd2-5b5c-4182-a22d-a29399ab6991">已结束[<font color=red>HOPECE140228-1 </font>][<font color=deeppink><strong>全<strong></font>]</a>

                                                            </td><td align="center" width="5%">

                                                                1.0

                                                            </td>

</tr><tr align="right">

    <td colspan="9"><span>1</span>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgContract$_ctl14$_ctl1','')">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgContract$_ctl14$_ctl2','')">3</a></td>

</tr>
```